# How to create different layers from a single variable in javascript using leaflet plugin?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have created a map using the following code. I have created map markers for the renewable energy plants in the US, specifically ones with primary fuel of hydro, solar and wind. What  I am having trouble with, is how do I create a layer control where I cant filter through on the map between the 3 energy sources. Please help!!

```
var myMap = L.map("map", {
  center: [39.0119, -98.4842],
  zoom: 5
});

// Adding tile layer
L.tileLayer("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}", {
  attribution: "© <a href='https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/'>Mapbox</a> © <a href='http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a> <strong><a href='https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/' target='_blank'>Improve this map</a></strong>",
  tileSize: 512,
  maxZoom: 18,
  zoomOffset: -1,
  id: "mapbox/streets-v11",
  accessToken: API_KEY
}).addTo(myMap);

var url = "USA.geojson";

d3.json(url, function(response) {
  // console.log(response.features[1].properties.capacity_mw);
  // console.log(response);
  console.log(response.features[1].geometry.coordinates);


       for (var i = 0; i < response.features.length; i++) {
        var geometry1 = response.features[i];
        // console.log(geometry1.geometry.coordinates)
        if (geometry1) {
          L.marker([geometry1.geometry.coordinates[1], geometry1.geometry.coordinates[0]])
          .bindPopup("<h2>" + geometry1.properties.name + "<h2> <hr> <h3>Primary Fuel " + geometry1.properties.primary_fuel + "</h3>")
          .addTo(myMap);




        }
      }


});
```

I am also attaching a snippet of the geojson file

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.5761,40.2003 ] }, "properties": { "country":"USA", "country_long":"United States of America", "name":"12 Applegate Solar LLC", "gppd_idnr":"USA0059371", "capacity_mw":1.9, "primary_fuel":"Solar", "other_fuel1":"", "other_fuel2":"", "other_fuel3":"", "commissioning_year":2012, "owner":"SunRay Power LLC", "source":"U.S. Energy Information Administration", "url":"http://www.eia.gov/electricity/data/browser/", "geolocation_source":"U.S. Energy Information Administration", "wepp_id":"", "year_of_capacity_data":2017, "generation_gwh_2013":2.41461, "generation_gwh_2014":2.35, "generation_gwh_2015":2.43, "generation_gwh_2016":2.492, "generation_gwh_2017":2.276, "estimated_generation_gwh":null } },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
// create groups to add the markers
var solarGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var hydroGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var windGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

// use the L.geoJSON to convert the geojson into layers
L.geoJSON(json,{
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    // create a marker and add them to the correct group
    if(feature.properties.primary_fuel === "Solar"){
        L.marker(layer.getLatLng())
          .bindPopup("<h2>" + feature.properties.name + "<h2> <hr> <h3>Primary Fuel " + feature.properties.primary_fuel + "</h3>")
          .addTo(solarGroup);
    }else if(feature.properties.primary_fuel === "Hydro"){
        L.marker(layer.getLatLng())
          .bindPopup("<h2>" + feature.properties.name + "<h2> <hr> <h3>Primary Fuel " + feature.properties.primary_fuel + "</h3>")
          .addTo(hydroGroup);
    } else if(feature.properties.primary_fuel === "Wind"){
        L.marker(layer.getLatLng())
          .bindPopup("<h2>" + feature.properties.name + "<h2> <hr> <h3>Primary Fuel " + feature.properties.primary_fuel + "</h3>")
          .addTo(windGroup);
    }
  }
})

// create Layer Control
var overlayMaps = {
    "Solar": solarGroup,
    "Hydro": hydroGroup,
    "Wind": windGroup
}
L.control.layers(null, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/cq43ktu5/

Comment: Thank you!!, it works. Will it be the same process to create  a heatmap using the capacity_mw variable, and also creating the different  layers to filter through

Comment: Yes sure. Please check the answer as correct, this helps me and others

Comment: Is there a way to change the color of the map markers at each specific layer, for example solar having red markers, wind having green markers and hydro blue?

Comment: yes you can change the icon of the marker.[Doc](https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/) or you can use a library like [Awesome Markers](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers)